# Get last of slice in each loop in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following sliced each loop:

```
<% @group.each_slice(3).with_index do |k, i| %>
    <% k.each do |k| %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I determine that I am on the last slice? Something like this:

```
<% k == @group.each_slice(3).last %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a good idea to precalculate `@group.each_slice(3)` (better to do it in a controller)

```
<% slices = @group.each_slice(3).to_a %>
```

You could divide your logic for head slices and last slice

```
<% slices[0..-2].with_index do |k, i| %>
<% end %>

<% slices[-1].with_index do |k, i| %>
<% end %>
```

Or you could check if it is last slice by its index

```
<% slices.with_index do |k, i| %>
  <% if i == slices.size - 1 %>
    ...
  <% else %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = @group.each_slice(3).to_a
x.each_with_index do |k, i|
  puts 'last' if i == x.length-1
  k.each do |k|
    puts k
  end
end
```